# Input text fields not receiving visual focus in Internet explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Following is the code for creating Text box:

```
<div class="entry-form">
    <div class="text">
        <asp:TextBox ID="serviceProviderNameTextBox" MaxLength="40" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS being used:

```
.entry-form .text {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 16.71em;
    height: 2.3em;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.entry-form .text input:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: #23acff 0 0 9px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #23acff 0 0 9px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #23acff;
}
```

As Box shadow property only works for Internet Explorer 9 & above, following code is used for IE8

```
.ie8 .entry-form .text input:focus {
outline: thin solid #23acff;
}
```

Even though outline property works well for drop-down lists i have created, it doesn't work for text inputs( either the generated outline is shorter or longer than text box size). 
I get the focus when using keyboard but it is not visual. Is there any way to get **visual focus** on Text boxes in IE8 using any other properties.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE8 doesn't support :focus, try input:active

Comment: I tried input: active but it's not working. I got the solution. I have added padding and width to control the outline around input text fields with : focus which makes it work.